# Oro commerce aplication installation error

Tags: node.js, symfony, ubuntu, orocommerce

This is the error  `ERROR   | Upgrade NodeJS to ">=16 <17" version`
I tried with all versions of node 16 till 17 but have the same error.
I am using ubuntu 22.04
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After changing the NodeJS version, is it required to clear the application cache before the retry.

You can do it by running `rm -rf var/cache/*` console command